# Android HDPI size is equal to iOS Retina size

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am using this tool http://androidpixels.net/ from past few weeks to see ratio of pixels between LDPI/MDPI/HDPI/XHDPI and it's quite helpful. What I understood on crude level is iOS 640x960 images are basically HDPI for android mobile devices. So I fill the HDPI cell with same image size and rest size is provided by this tool. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

HDPI is a density bucket, not a resolution.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html